# Ethernet Hub and Subscription VPN Service

Tags: networking, vpn, ethernet

Is it possible to configure a network hub to connect to VPN service such as Private Internet Access and then connect multiple devices to the hub. I live in an apartment which provides internet via a single Ethernet connection and I want to set up a small network with my PC and a few Raspberry Pi which connect to the internet through the VPN.  If so can anyone recommend a reasonably priced hub?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ethernet hubs are dumb electronic devices. They can't be configured for anything. They're like repeaters, but with many connectors.

Comment: Any suggestions how I can I achieve what I have described above?  Should I use a router and disable the wireless mode?

Answer (score 0):

What you require is a router which supports acting as a VPN.
A good way to do this is to get a router which supports [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/OpenVPN) (or Tomato or equivalent), flash it to use DD-WRT and set up the VPN from that.

@mikelo's answer is half correct, but "cheap d-link" routers work fine if flashed dd-wrt, and any provider who supports your routers VPN client will work fine [ OpenVPN providers would be my choice as OpenVPN is relatively easy to set up and very, very robust.]